# $lookup is not working with $match in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, match, lookup

I want to join documents from two collections, based on a specific matching id given by the user.

The users collection is structured like this:

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58946773ab022b192814b586"), 
  "name" : "Josef Rakicj", 
  "uId" : "1485936031178", 
  "email" : "xxx@gmail.com", 
  "type" : "Dealer", 
  "__v" : 0
}
```

And the ads collection is structured like this:

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58bfe1a6e809982168458a5e"), 
  "adId" : "1488970150316", 
  "uId" : "1485936031178",
  "title" : "Sorry, free.facebook.com isn't available in your country right now", 
  "type" : "0",
  "__v" : 0
}
```

So, I am trying to execute `$lookup` in two collections by perform `$match`, using the code below.

```js
 router.get('/ad-details/:adId', function(req,res,next){ 
    var paramid=JSON.stringify(req.params.adId); 
    Adpost.aggregate(
      {$match:{adId:paramid}},
      { $lookup: 
        {
          from: "users",
          localField: "uId", 
          foreignField: "uId", 
          as: "postby "
        }
      },function(err,data){
        if(err){res.json(err)}
            else{
                res.json(data)
                console.log(data)
            }
    })
 });
```

Above aggregate is working fine in `Mongo Shell`. But when I am applying this query in Node.js then its not working and sending empty data.

Please let me know what is the exactly error.

Comment: Place your both collection sample data.

Comment: users Collection:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58946773ab022b192814b586"),
    "name" : "Josef Rakicj",
    "uId" : "1485936031178", 
    "email" : "xxx@gmail.com", 
    "type" : "Dealer",
    "__v" : 0
}

ads Collection:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bfe1a6e809982168458a5e"),
    "adId" : "1488970150316",
    "uId" : "1485936031178",
    "title" : "Sorry, free.facebook.com isn't available in your country right now",  
    "type" : "0", 
    "__v" : 0
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation query must be an array just put your query into an array

```
 router.get('/ad-details/:adId', function(req,res,next){ 
    Adpost.aggregate([{$match:{adId:req.params.adId}},{ $lookup: { from: "users",localField: "uId", foreignField: "uId", as: "postby "}}],function(err,data){
        if(err){res.json(err)}
            else{
                res.json(data)
                console.log(data)
            }
    })
 });
```

And you don't need to stringify the request param.

Comment: When I make it an Array then its throwing an error: `Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`

Comment: can you put your query here.(after making array)

Comment: router.get('/ad-details/:adId', function(req,res,next){ 
  var paramid=JSON.stringify(req.params.adId); 
  Adpost.aggregate([
   {$match:{
    adId:paramid
   }
  },
   { $lookup: { 
    from: "users",
    localField: "uId", 
    foreignField: "uId", 
    as: "postby "
   }
  },function(err,data){
   if(err){res.json(err)}
    else{
     res.json(data)
     console.log(data)
    }
  }])
 });

Comment: your array bracket is on wrong place, just put first parameter as array of aggregate function, second is callback function.        router.get('/ad-details/:adId', function(req,res,next){ 
  var paramid=JSON.stringify(req.params.adId); 
  Adpost.aggregate([ 
    {$match:{ adId:paramid } }, 
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "uId", foreignField: "uId", as: "postby " } }]
    ,function(err,data){ if(err){res.json(err)} else{ res.json(data) console.log(data) } }) });

Comment: see the query i answered

Comment: No... Still not working as per your Answer... throwing empty array

Comment: As I described in my question... My query is working fine in Mongo Shell and giving the expected result.... But its not working in with node.js

Comment: What you use for mongodb to connect like mongoose or somethig. can you place your file  code here with your sample documents that match query condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138179/discussion-between-saurabh-sharma-and-vaibhav-patil).